# When doing multiple SQL queries should I try to use same connection?

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

So sometimes in my Java application I need to send multiple queries to my MySQL database in the same method.

I am using connection pooling in my application:

```
private static final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    static {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://--------:---/agenda?useSSL=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("----");
        dataSource.setPassword("----");
    }
```

I have a method in my Database class:

```
public static Employee getEmployee(int id) {
        Employee employee = null;
        try { String query = "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE entityId = " + id + " LIMIT 0, 1;";
            Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
            java.sql.Statement indexStmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet indexRs = indexStmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (indexRs.next()) {
                employee = new Employee(indexRs.getInt(1),
                        indexRs.getString(3), indexRs.getString(4),
                        indexRs.getString(5), indexRs.getString(6));
            }
            indexStmt.close();
            indexRs.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return employee;    
    }
```

Should I take the time to try to use the same `Connection con = DataBase.getSource()`  Or is it fine to just get a new `connection` from the pool even if I am doing something like this?

```
init() {

    Employee employee1= DataBase.getEmployee(11);
    Employee employee2 = DataBase.getEmployee(12);
}
```

I could implement something that these two lines of code would use the same `connection` but would that be wise or unnecessary?

//side note the employee id is never inputed from the user so SQL injection is not possible there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would mean running your own connection pooling on top of the existing connection pooling. To make these two layers interact cleanly will not be easy.

But you'd probably get a performance improvement by passing an opened Connection into your getEmployee() method, so that you can acquire your connection outside, use it for multiple consecutive calls, and then close it. But I can't tell how much performance difference it makes, and it surely makes your code less elegant, compared to the current architecture.